# Вывод элементов на побочной диагонали массива

Tags: javascript

Почему то не работает,подскажите как поправить?

```js
var data = [
  1, 2, 3,
  4, 5, 6,
  7, 8, 9
];
var n = data.length;
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    if (j == n - i + 1) {
      console.log(data[i][j]) //выводит 7 раз undefined
    }
  }
}
```

На выходе должно быть 3,5,7, но вводит `undefined`

Comment: вопрос немного не по теме, но почему вы используете и var и let?

Comment: Данные в виде **одномерного** массива - это **так надо** или **ошибка**?

Comment: AGS17 да, так надо

Comment: Это один из тех вопросов, где автор может самостоятельно поставить breakpoint и отладить код, но, почему-то, этого не делает

Comment: Если у тебя одномерный массив, то что ты надеешься получить такой записью `data[i][j]` ?

Answer (score 2):

- Для квадратной матрицы шаг (step) будет равен квадратному корню из количества элементов (n) в одномерном массиве минус 1 (так как шаг начинается с нуля).
- Начинать нужно, конечно же, не с нуля, а сразу с шага (ибо смысла нет начинать с нуля).
- Заканчивать также нужно на последнем элементе диагонали (n - step)

Выглядит это будет так:

```js
var matrix2D = [
  1, 2, 
  3, 4
];

var matrix3D = [
  1, 2, 3,
  4, 5, 6,
  7, 8, 9
];

var matrix4D = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 
  5, 6, 7, 8, 
  9, 10, 11, 12,
  13, 14, 15, 16
];

getSquareMatrixDiagData(matrix2D);
console.log("-------------------");
getSquareMatrixDiagData(matrix3D);
console.log("-------------------");
getSquareMatrixDiagData(matrix4D);

function getSquareMatrixDiagData(arr){
    var n = arr.length;
    var step = Math.sqrt(arr.length) - 1;

    for (var i = step; i < n - step; i += step) { 
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала надо задать **многомерный** массив, когда как в оригинальном коде - **не** многомерный. Именно поэтому console.log(data[i][j]) выдает undefined, т.к [j] не существует, массив состоит из 9 штук [i].
 Перенос строки при создании нового массива ничего не даст, многомерный массив объявляется так:

```
var data = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];
```

А с правильным массивом автор сам наверняка сможет решить задачу.

Comment: так суть в том, что по условию одномерный массив) Но в таком случае запись `data[i][j]` не верна

Comment: Если изначально задан одномерный массив, то не надо обращаться с ним, как с двумерным. По-сути у одномерного массива никакой главной диагонали нет, т.к это обычный столбик значений.

Comment: согласен, в комментариях выше об этом и речь

Comment: А что по условию задачи можно делать с этим массивом?

Comment: я не знаю условия задачи..)

Comment: Только сейчас понял, что говорю не с автором вопроса) Если использовать именно одномерный, то ответ в теме уже дан Алексеем Шиманским.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
  1, 2, 3,
  4, 5, 6,
  7, 8, 9
];

var n = Math.sqrt(data.length);

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  console.log(data[(i+1)*(n-1)])
}
```

Comment: Норм! Только плюс я тебе не поставлю, я жмот!)